# Calling functions with or without "const" signature in C++

Tags: c++, constants

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object
{
public:
    Object() {}

    void Print() const
    {
        cout << "const" << endl;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        cout << "mutable" << endl;
    }
};

void print_obj(const Object& obj)
{
    obj.Print();
}

int main()
{
    Object       obj1;
    const Object obj2;
    Object*const pobj1 = &obj1;

    print_obj(obj1);
    print_obj(obj2);

    obj1.Print();
    obj2.Print();

    pobj1->Print();

    return 0;
}
```

I know the output is

```
const
const
mutable
const
mutable
```

I guess for const object, it looks for the const function. Otherwise the mutable function. But why is the last one mutable?

Comment: `pobj1` is a const pointer to non-const `Object`. The pointer itself cannot be modified (cannot be made to point to something else), but the object it points to can be modified, and so a non-const overload is called. Note that `Object * const` is not the same type as `Object const *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is the last one mutable?

```
Object*const pobj1 = &obj1;
```

declares `pobj1` to be a `const` pointer to a non-`const` object. The object is still mutable but the pointer is not.

After the variable is initialized, you will not be able to change it to point to another variable.

```
pobj1 = &obj2;    // Not OK.
```

But you can still change the variable it points to and call non-`const` member functions of the class through the pointer.

```
*pobj1 = obj2;    // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

> But why is the last one mutable?

This is because the declaration is `Object* const pobj1`. Since we are working with pointers there are 2 const possibilities.

```
const Object* const pobj1 OR Object const * const pobj1
^^1^^         ^^2^^                 ^^1^^   ^^2^^
// 1 applies to the types (i.e., Object)
// 2, which is what you're using applies to the pointer, therefore you're using a non-const Object
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Object*const pobj1 = &obj1;
```

declares pobj1 to be a const pointer to a non-const object.  If you doubt that,
just change it to

```
Object*const pobj2 = &obj2;
```

This won't compile because it throws away a const qualifier of obj2.

BTW, the restriction is that for const object, it can ONLY use const functions.  'const' after the parenthesis means that 'this*' pointer will be treated as a pointer to a const object within the method.

For non-const objects, it can use both const and non-const methods, but it will chose to use non-const first (if both are defined).

Answer (score -1):

I believe you meant "const Object*". "const" can be applied to the pointer and/or the object the pointer is pointing to. The twist is that "Object * const" is the same as "Object const*".

Comment: `Object const *` is the same as `const Object *`